# Any representation of U(1) admits an invariant Hermitian inner product

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, hermitian-matrices

Let $R: U(1) \to \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb C)$ be a representation, let $e^{i\theta} \in U(1)$, and let $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ be the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then, the Hermitian inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ $$\langle u,v \rangle_R := \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \langle R(e^{i\theta})u,R(e^{i\theta})v \rangle \,  \mathrm{d}\theta $$ is invariant under the action of $R$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$, meaning $\langle u,v \rangle_R = \langle R(e^{i\phi})u,R(e^{i\phi})v \rangle_R$.

**Proof**

It should be really easy to prove, but I am getting stuck on the last step. $$\langle R(e^{i\phi})u,R(e^{i\phi})v \rangle_R = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \langle R(e^{i\phi})R(e^{i\theta})u,R(e^{i\phi})R(e^{i\theta})v \rangle \,  \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \langle R(e^{i(\theta+\phi)})u,R(e^{i(\theta+\phi)})v \rangle \,  \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\phi}^{\phi+2\pi} \langle R(e^{i\theta'})u,R(e^{i\theta'})v \rangle \,  \mathrm{d}\theta'$$ Where I used the fact that $R$ is a representation and a change of variable $\theta' = \theta + \phi$. This is almost $\langle u, v \rangle_R$, except for the boundaries of integration shifted by $\phi$. Is this still equivalent to the original inner product? I should also note that I can't use the classification of the representations of $U(1)$ with $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb C) \ni R(e^{i\theta}) = diag(e^{im_k\theta})_n$ with $k=1,...,n$ and $m_k \in \mathbb Z$ since this lemma is supposed to be used to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the right idea, you just missed a crucial fact. $d\theta$ is a Haar measure, so it's almost by definition that

$$ \int_{[0,2\pi]} f(\theta+\phi) \,d\theta = \int_{[0,2\pi]} f(\theta)\,d\theta.$$

This trick works for any compact abelian group actually. Given a compact abelian group $G$ with Haar measure $dg$, Hilbert space $H$ with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, and representation $\rho$ of $G$ on $\mathcal{B}(H)$, the inner product

$$ \langle f_1,f_2\rangle_{\rho} = \int_G \langle \rho(g)f_1, \rho(g)f_2\rangle\,dg$$

is invariant under actions by $\rho$, i.e.

$$ \langle \rho(g')f_1,\rho(g')f_2\rangle_{\rho} = \langle f_1,f_2\rangle_{\rho}.$$

This lets you work with unitary representations. It's called a group averaging trick.

Comment: Indeed. I'd emphasize that the interval $[0,2\pi]$, while an elementary thing, is _not_ a group, while the circle (obtained by sticking the endpoints together, and/or as quotient $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$) _is_ a group... and periodic functions _descend_ to that group. And that group has no boundary to mar "integration by parts". :)

Comment: Yes! The group operations are really all mod $2\pi$. (But really better thought of as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ depending on where you want to put $2\pi$'s) since that connects to other things we know and love.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what a Haar measure is. Can you elaborate a bit more with an intuitive example of what is going on, or provide a reference where I can look it up? Thank you!

Comment: @Siupa look up Folland's *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis.* But really all you need to know is that your group operation is really mod $2\pi$, so that $[\phi, \phi+2\pi]$ is actually $[\phi, 2\pi]\cup [2\pi,2\pi+\phi]$. This last bit mod $2\pi$ is the same as $[0,\phi]$. When you put the pieces together, you get $[0,2\pi]$ all over again. You should think of this as integrating over the circle. If you multiple a circle by $e^{i\phi}$, it's the same circle, so your integration is over the same set, regardless of start and end point.